# Encoding used by Kusto Web Explorer to generate shareable links

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Which encoding is used to encode the kql query when using the ‘Link to clipboard’ button on Kusto Web Explorer?

For example, the link for the query 'StormEvents | count' is 'https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=**H4sIAAAAAAAAAwsuyS/KdS1LzSspVqhRSM4vzSsBALU2eHsTAAAA**'.

I tried base64 decoding the query param, but the decoder complains it is an invalid input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a combination of gzip compression followed by base64 encoding.

As mentioned in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/rest/deeplink#specifying-the-query-or-control-command-in-the-uri